# How to create a button clicked EventHandler in Xamarin.Forms with code-behind?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mobile-development

I want to allow a user to click on an **Add Term** button on my **HomePage** to create a new term page. I want a button to be created for navigating to that term. I have created the button to add terms but I can't figure out how to give the newly created button an EventHandler for navigation. This is what I have so far:

```
private string crrntTerm;
private List<Term> termList;

private void addTermBtnForTest()
        {

            Term termTest = new Term()
            {
                TermTitle = "Term 1", 
                CreateDate = System.DateTime.Now
            };

            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
            {
                conn.CreateTable<Term>();
                conn.Insert(termTest);
                crrntTerm = termTest.TermID.ToString();
                termList = conn.Table<Term>().ToList();
            }


            Button testBtn = new Button()
            {
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                FontSize = 20,
                Margin = 30,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                Clicked += GoToTermButton_Clicked //Error: Invalid initializer member declarator
            };

            testBtn.BindingContext = termTest;
            testBtn.SetBinding(Button.TextProperty, "TermTitle");


            layout.Children.Add(testBtn);
        }//end addTermBtnForTest

private async void GoToTermButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // Code to go to appropriate page
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? What is your problem (cannot compile or what) ? Any error messages? Need more information to help you out.

Comment: Hi, no it will not compile. The 'Clicked' property in my Button 'testBtn' is redlined with the error 'Invalid initializer member declarator'. I don't know what the proper syntax would be  for the Clicked EventHandler in C#. I know if I were trying to do the same thing in XAML I would write 'Clicked="GoToTermButton_Clicked "'. So, I am looking for the equivalent in the code-behind.

Comment: Did you defined the method `GoToTermButton_Clicked` in your file?

Comment: Yes, I just put an alert in it to get it to work. @Amjad provided a solution that solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the event after initializing the button it wont give an error.

```
 Button testBtn = new Button()
            {
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                FontSize = 20,
                Margin = 30,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                
            };
testBtn.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>{....}
//testBtn.Clicked += async (sender, args) => GoToTermButton_Clicked (sender,args);
```

Comment: Thank you! That takes care of my problem.